# Encoding mixed language attachment filenames

Tags: java, encoding, jakarta-mail

I try hard to send an email with Spring's MimeMessageHelper with an attachment with characters from different languages:

```
MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
// ...
helper.addAttachment("éàè öäü русский алфавит.pdf", bytes, "application/pdf");
```

Whatever I do, the filename in Gmail always appears like:

```
?UTF-8?B?0JDQutGC0LXRgNGLLdCb0Y7QutGB0LXQvNCx0YPRgA==?= =?UTF-8?B?0LMtMjAxOS0xMSDQvNCw0Y8ucGRm?=
```

I tried:

```
MimeUtility.encodeText("éàè öäü русский алфавит.pdf", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name(), "Q");
MimeUtility.encodeWord(...) // same result
```

and also setting:

```
System.setProperty("mail.mime.splitlongparameters", "false");
System.setProperty("mail.mime.encodeparameters", "false"); // or true
System.setProperty("mail.mime.charset", "utf-8");
```

does not make a change.

If I remove the non-cyrillic characters (éàè öäü) from the filename, then the filename is encoded well, just without any MimeUtility.encode calls.

But in my use-case I can have mixed language filenames.

Even when I change `éàè öäü русский алфавит.pdf` to `2019 русский алфавит.pdf` the display of the filename stays bad. But just leaving `русский алфавит.pdf` makes it display correctly in Gmail.

Why is that?

I use Spring Boot 1.5.21 and Java 8 on Fedora 30.

Comment: What's wrong with the UTF-8 encoded filename?  Is the name wrong?  When I decode it I get "Актеры-Люксембург-2019-11 мая.pdf".

Comment: The issue is that Gmail does now show the encoded filename but the ?UTF-8... string. Maybe it's a Gmail issue... But I tried mailing a file named "éàè öäü русский алфавит.pdf" from Gmail to Gmail, and the filename showed up correctly. Only when I mail it from my code the attachment is shown as ?UTF-8...

Comment: This [JavaMail FAQ article about encoding file names](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#encodefilename) explains the issue; you're using a non-standard encoding technique.